# Gollum wiki for multiple projects

Tags: git, wiki, web-farm, gollum-wiki

I like [Gollum](https://github.com/github/gollum) for wiki, but one instance seems to be able to handle a single repository only.

Is some similar project out there that handles multiple repos,
or an out-of-the-box solution that maintains multiple Gollum projects instances?

By the *maintain* i mean: creating repos, list all the repos, ...

Answer (score 1):

I just created two different wikis:

```
gollum --page-file-dir wiki1 my_repos
```

(Control-c to stop running gollum)

```
gollum --page-file-dir wiki2 my_repos
```

I created a `home.mediawiki` file as the homepage for each. So they are occupying two different namespaces.

To edit these at the same time, I suppose I'd learn to use a different port for the second instance of gollum, or just commit notes to one directory or the other (wiki1 or wiki2) through my text editor, which is probably what I'll be doing anyway.

Since wiki1 and wiki2 are directories on a computer with a GUI interface, I'd just use Finder/Windows Explorer/whatever to maintain the list of them.

Does that meet your needs?

Comment: No, what i want to achieve is to have the Gollum page which let me create, delete new wiki. Similar what github let you do, but it could be a much simpler

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to do this via desktop shortcuts. The executable command is as follows:

```
bash -c "bport='$(jot -r 1 10000 20000)'; gollum /path/to/wiki --port $bport & chromium-browser http://localhost:$bport ; wait $(pgrep 'chromium-browser localhost:$bport') && kill $(pgrep -f 'gollum /path/to/wiki') &"
```

This pseudorandomizes a port to bind gollum to and then applies that port to access the wiki. Once chromium closes, the wait status jumps to kill the gollum process using pgrep to get its pid. Thus each gollum instance for each wiki opened through the desktop will be different and gollum can live with other gollums and not be so glum.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub was using Gollum in the past, to host the wikis (optionally) associated with each repo. Thus, they had to have a solution for exactly this problem. It seems like their code-name for this was **Smeagol**. Their solution is not publicly available.

There are however, some Open Source projects with the same goal - also called Smeagol.
The noteworthy ones according to my own search are (as of mid 2020):

1. https://github.com/cloudogu/smeagol
   (Java, MIT)
2. https://github.com/schnatterer/smeagol-galore
   (Java, MIT, based on cloudogu's implementation)
3. https://github.com/journeyman-cc/smeagol
   (Clojure, GPLv2)

I have not yet tested them, but the second option (*smeagol-galore*)
sounds like a pretty good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [big-gollum](https://github.com/oponder/big-gollum), but it doesn't look particularly active.